# how to change text in datagridview text on condition .

Tags: winforms, datagridview, c#-3.0

I am using a datagridview and I want to display do conditional formatting means when I get for a cell `M` then I want to display `Married`.I try this but not sucess.

Here is my code:

```
private void masterDataGridView_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
      {
          try
          {
              for (int i = 0; i <= masterDataGridView.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
              {
                  String Value = masterDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[17].Value.ToString();
                  if (Value == "M")
                  {
                      e.Value = "Male";
                  }
              }
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {

          }
      }
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Do you get an exception?

Comment: object refreance not set as instance of object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a little work this code work for me very fine . I am posting it may be any other can use the code

```
private void masterDataGridView_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{

    if (masterDataGridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name.Equals("Gender"))
                      {
                          string _val = e.Value as string;
                          if (_val == null)
                              return;


                          switch (_val)
                          {
                              case  "M" :
                                  e.Value = "Male";
                                  break;
                              case "F":
                                  e.Value = "Female";
                                  break;

                          }

                      }
}
```

Chearss ....

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use the [`.CellFormatting`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting.aspx) event with `for loop statement` which is not the proper way.

> The CellFormatting event occurs every time each cell is painted, so
>   you should avoid lengthy processing when handling this event. This
>   event also occurs when the cell FormattedValue is retrieved or its
>   GetFormattedValue method is called.

So every time the cell is painted, the `for loop` is running.

Try this:

```
private void masterDataGridView_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex >= 17 && e.ColumnIndex <= 24)
        {
            if (e.Value == "M")
                e.Value = "Married";
            else
                e.Value = "Not Married";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: is i need to give the columnIndex for this

Comment: yes but not works i have 24 cell in my grid but it stop after 14 no

Comment: if that so, in `columnIndex = 17` all cells are converted to "Married"? i am right?

Comment: can please clarify.. what is the exactly you want.. in your question, do you want the `M` converted to `Married` and your example is `Male`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25216/discussion-between-a-goutam-and-spajce)